# Access violation in DirectX11 CreatePixelShader with initialized PS in a ID3DBlob

Tags: c++, directx, shader, directx-11

I'm doing some directX and for some reason the **device->CreatePixelShader** gives me an access violation error
I have initialised PS in the **ID3DBlob** and the  **pShader as a ID3D11PixelShader**  which tells me that it NULL after I debug it seems that there is nothing wrong there, any help? Many thanks

```
// Create the input layout
ID3DBlob *VS, *PS;

D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"shaders.shader", 0, 0, "VShader", "vs_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS, 0, 0);
D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"shaders.shader", 0, 0, "PShader", "vs_5_0", 0, 0, 0, &PS, 0, 0);

device->CreateVertexShader(VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &vShader);
device->CreatePixelShader(PS->GetBufferPointer(), PS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &pShader);

context->VSSetShader(vShader, 0, 0);
context->PSSetShader(pShader, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Note that D3DX11 is deprecated. You can use the ``D3DCompile`` API directly as ``D3DX11CompileFromFile`` is just a wrapper for it. See [HLSL, FXC, and D3DCompile](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That pixel shader won't have compiled using vs_5_0 as a profile. Check your HRESULTs!

Comment: Hi Przemek, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

A good mechanism for religiously checking `HRESULT` return values is to use a macro around all such calls that checks the result for success and throws on error.  I outline a simple strategy for doing this in [Chapter 1](http://user.xmission.com/~legalize/book/download/01-Introduction.pdf) of my free book ["The Direct3D Graphics Pipeline"](https://legalizeadulthood.wordpress.com/the-direct3d-graphics-pipeline/).